# Trying to send a responsive email using PHP mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a responsive email template in a php file and trying to send it with PHP mailer with no success. My code looks like this.

```
$m = new PHPMailer;
$m ->isSMTP();
$m->SMTPAuth=true;

// debugging
// $m->SMTODebug=1
// endof debug
$m->Host="smtp.gmail.com";
$m->Username="example@gmail.com";
$m->Password="blahblah";
$m->SMTPSecure='ssl';
$m->Port=465;
$m->isHtml(true);

$m->Subject = 'Welcome to Efie';
$m->msgHTML(file_get_contents('functions/register-email.php'), dirname(__FILE__));
$m->FromName="Contact Form Efie";
$m->AddAddress($email,$fname);
if($m->send()) {
    echo '<p class="errors bg-success text-success">Email   Received</p>';
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a responsive email template? If it has Javascript in the email, most mail readers will ignore the JS.

Comment: Do you have any errors that you can share ? Instinctively I'd say you don't have any MTA (mail transfer agent) installed on your server, but I might be totaly wrong.

Comment: If you are using gmail you might want to allow the sign in for less secure app as is mentioned here https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255.

Comment: I am using zurb email template..  I receive the email but I have some variables in the register-email.php file that I need sent in the email.  I want to be able to parse the variables when they are sent

Comment: @krtek no I don't,  just not seeing my parsed variables in the email

Comment: `$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('functions/register-email.php'), dirname(__FILE__));` why $mail not $m?  file_get_contents will not share the same variable scope as the calling script.

Comment: @Progrock actually it's m.  I forgot to update that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't anything to do with it being responsive - that's just a matter of using the CSS media queries in the Zurb CSS, it doesn't need any javascript.

The problem you're seeing is that `file_get_contents` literally gets the contents of the file, it does not run it as a PHP script. There are several ways to solve this.

You can `include` the file while assigning it to a variable, like this:

```
$body = include 'functions/register-email.php';
$m->msgHTML($body, dirname(__FILE__));
```

The problem with this approach is that you can't just have content sitting in the file, you need to `return` it as a value, so your template would be something like:

```
<?php
$text = <<<EOT
<html>
<body>
<h1>$headline</h1>
</body>
</html>
EOT;
return $text;
```

An easier approach is to use output buffering, which makes the template file simpler:

```
ob_start();
include 'functions/register-email.php';
$body = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$m->msgHTML($body, dirname(__FILE__));
```

and the template would be simply:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1><?php echo $headline; ?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Either way, the template file will have access to your local variables and interpolation will work.

There are other options such as using `eval`, but it's inefficient and easy to 
do things wrong.

Using output buffering is the simplest, but if you want lots more flexibility and control, use a templating language such as [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net) or [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org).

For working with Zurb, you really need a CSS inliner such as [emogrifier](https://github.com/jjriv/emogrifier) to post-process your rendered template, otherwise things will fall apart in gmail and other low-quality mail clients.

FYI, this stack - Zurb templates, Smarty, emogrifier, PHPMailer - is exactly what's used in [smartmessages.net](https://info.smartmessages.net), which I built.

Comment: Glad that worked, please mark my answer as correct - click the tick!