# php variables in a html email template using phpmailer

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

Okay I've got a pretty loooooooong html email template file with more than +700 lines.

I have tried copy n paste it as the html body in phpmailer and send emails that way but it doesn't work, it's picking up other " and ' and throwing errors. I tried using phtml file and that didn't work out either...

So if I have variables like $name   $surname in a email template +700 lines, how can I actually display them?

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39265928/trying-to-send-a-responsive-email-using-php-mailer/39267095#39267095). It's not well named, but it's doing what you're asking.

Comment: @Synchro Somehow that solution with ob didn't work... I had the email template in a php file with variables like <?php echo $variable; ?> and then in my phpmailer file this $mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "$customer_name completed quote for a marquee.";

    
ob_start();
include 'email_template.php';
$message = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();    
    
$mail->Body = $message;

Comment: That looks right, but you need to be a bit more specific than "didn't work".

Comment: Nevermind, it works. Something was screwing up the ?> tags in the html. Thanks a bunch !